# How to apply MySQL check Constraint on database using XAMPP

Tags: xampp

How can we apply check constraint on a table's field using XAMPP? When I apply the check constraint on the database, the query is executed, but the constraint does not apply.

Comment: To me, this is too broad to answer as not being clear ... can you give more details? Even better, some code snippets (some SQL, or whatever) of what you are trying do.

Comment: Iwant to apply check constraint on a feild of table in Xampp. I write the following query   ALTER TABLE customer ADD CHECK (Price<20); this query has executed successfully but check constraint does not apply.

Comment: I have also written the query..                                                                             CREATE TABLE customer(id  int(11), name varchar(20), price  int(11),    CHECK (price<20) ); but the problem is still there and there is no issue when we enter the a value greater then 20.

Comment: MySQL's documentation says: `The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.` That is mentioned at both `ALTER TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE` syntax pages.

Comment: how can we solve this problem